# Function and Triggers in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

how to do the equivalent code in ORACLE

The code is made for Postgresql.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION emp_stamp() RETURNS trigger AS emp_stamp
    BEGIN
        -- BODY

    END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_stamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE emp_stamp();
```

Comment: The functionality of `emp_stamp` is crucial here. If you tell us what it does we can explain how to do the equivalent thing in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Postresql. If you could explain what this piece of code does, it might be easier to assist.  Meanwhile, see if this example helps.

Function accepts employee's `EMPNO` and returns its `MAX` `salary` from the `salaries` table (doesn't make much sense, but that replaces your `--body` comment).

```
create or replace function emp_stamp (par_empno in emp.empno%type)
  return emp.sal%type
is
  retval emp.sal%type;
begin
  select max(sal)
    into retval
    from salaries
    where empno = par_empno;

  return retval;
end;
/
```

Trigger calls that function and sets employee's `emp.sal` column to value returned by the function.

```
create or replace trigger trg_emp_stamp
  before insert or update on emp
  for each row
begin
  :new.sal := emp_stamp(:new.empno);
end;
/
```

Comment: Unlike Postgres, Oracle does not have the trigger function construct. The code necessary code is placed directly into the trigger, or as @Littlefoot indicates the trigger calls a standalone function.  So "create trigger ... begin *body* end.